# Precis Excercise Guidance

Tags: discussion

I am practicing "Precis Writing" now a days. I checked that there is no TAG regarding precis or summary. I want to ask where or on which stack I can put such questions regarding precis writing.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You may find this is [on-topic](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [Writers.SE](https://writers.stackexchange.com/), as it could fall into their "critique" category.

Questions will need to be carefully scoped, as explained in their [relevant Meta post](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/167/5480):

> You must have either a **specific question** about your sample or **specific guidelines** for the critique. Below would be examples of on-topic questions:
>
> - "Where are the unneeded words?"
> - "Does this character introduction seem smooth?"
> - "How can I show more and tell less in this instance?"
> - "Does this paragraph make you want to keep reading?"
> - "How can I improve this dialogue to create a sense of suspense?"
>
> Your paragraph must be a concise illustration of your larger question
>
> Your question must be phrased in such a way that answers can be objectively voted on by the community here.
>
> Your question should encourage answers which explain their reasoning and back up any subjective statements with experience or recognized authorities.
>
> While your question should give us an idea of your own style and what you intend to do with your included writing, the question should encourage fair and impartial answers.
>
> Please do not ask us to proofread your work for grammar, spelling, or punctuation issues.

There appear to be no questions on Writers Meta about precis techniques and results, nor do they have [precis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precis) or [summary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summary) tags. Before jumping straight in, I would suggest **asking a similar question on their Meta site,** referencing the critique guidelines I've linked to and quoted here, and asking for specific guidance on how to make precis on-topic.

It is fairly certain that such questions would not be on-topic on ELU, as they don't fall into any of these categories:

> - Word choice and usage
> - Grammar
> - Etymology (history of words’ development)
> - Dialect differences
> - Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
> - Spelling and punctuation

If you get a satisfactory response (that is "Yes, Writers is the right place and here's how to do it"), do return here and answer your own question with a link to the advice you're given. If they say Writers is the wrong place, then a comment here saying "Nope, they say No" would help people in the future who have the question.